# Clash with dutch Babel and tikzcd

Tags: babel, tikz-cd

I was trying to make a commutative diagram using something like `\arrow[r, "A"]` at some point, and I kept getting weird errors. I finally found out that I got no errors if I removed "dutch" from `\usepackage[dutch, english]`. Alternatively, I can get it to work by enclosing the tikzcd environment with `\shorthandoff{"}...\shorthandon{"}`. Apparently, something in "dutch" clashes with the use of " in `\arrow[r, "A"]`. Two questions.

- What is exactly the clash here? What is "predefined" or whatever in the dutch option in babel that does not like the use of "" in the arrow command?
- Is there a nicer solution to this problem? The only thing I can think of is to redefine the tikzcd environment to be something like

`\shorthandoff{"}\begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd}\shorthandon{"}`

This is really just wrapping the earlier inelegant solution in a large blanket, so I'm not a fan.

Loading tikzlibrary{babel} solves the issue if one does not wrap the tikzcd in an align environment (and there is not a good reason to do this). I'm still curious what exactly align messes up here, though.

After all, a MWE. I do something like this.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch, english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
        A \arrow[r, "A"] \& B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` probably makes `"` an active character. Did you try `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`?

Comment: This is what I have read elsewhere. I have tried your suggestion, but it gives me the same error. Edit: this does work in the normal case, my apologies. Now I should provide a MWE, and I will.

Comment: If the babel tikz lib does not work please post a full minimal example others can copy and test

Comment: It does fix the error with e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
                                & C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}`. But since @BPasternak did not post a minimal working example, it is basically impossible to help without a crystal ball.

Comment: @frougon Perhaps read the edit to my comment first :D.

Comment: And there are still [people](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536731/aligning-indices-in-multiple-sums-with-overline?noredirect=1#comment1356082_536731) with 2400+ rep who insist that they don't need to post an MWE!

Comment: Honestly, if I wasn't such an idiot as to use the align-environment in this case, your first comment (or me reading the tikzcd manual properly) would have solved my problem without an MWE. I don't like this public shaming thingy either, bruh.

Comment: This proves once again that preparing an MWE allows people to solve many problems *by themselves*.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I solved it without preparing the MWE. I did realise what was unstandard about my case by thinking about what I did that's not necessary to have such a commutative diagram with 2 languages. In any case, to make your point you do not have refer to another user.

Comment: I referred to the user (and did not name him) because his behavior is extremely selfish; I don't see why I would refrain to do so.

Comment: Because it serves no other purpose than providing anecdotal proof with a sample size of 1 that your statement is correct. But people will believe this without an example. What are you, a policeman here? You named him by linking directly to him!

Comment: I have a very wild guess as to where my downvote comes from!

Comment: Yet you are mistaken. Do you want me to show you?

Comment: Nah, I believe you, don't worry. It was a wild guess.

Comment: I added an upvoted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First some general words. We invite to present the question with a minimal example of code for several reasons:

- often the question is presented with no hint about the actual error message(s);
- preparing a MWE sometimes helps in spotting the error or in finding a workaround;
- it's kind to whoever wants to help.

More specific to your post, you probably had *two* sources for errors. One due to `babel` making `"` active for Dutch, the other one because of using `tikzcd` inside an `align` environment.

Solution for the first problem: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Solution for the second problem: use the `ampersand replacement=\&` option and `\&` in the body of `tikzcd` to mark column delimiters. But also `\shorthandoff{"}` and `\shorthandon{"}`.

Why is that? Because `align` (and the other `amsmath` display environments) absorb the contents as the argument to a macro and so `tikzcd` cannot do the trick it usually does to `&`. Neither it can do the job for `"`.

If you're used to generally employ `align` or `align*` for single equation (or diagram), change your habit and use `equation` or `equation*` in these cases. It's semantically sounder, more efficient and avoids doing some tricks. Moreover, the spacing is better. I guess you can spot below the difference in spacing, which is excessive with `align*`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dutch, english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-2]
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r, "A"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2][1-2]
\shorthandoff{"}\begin{align*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
        A \arrow[r, "A"] \& B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{align*}\shorthandon{"}%
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I obviously agree, but I do think that the words "often" and "sometimes" definitively apply and leave room for questions without an MWE. Moving on now, MWEing everything and anything, happy times.

Comment: @BPasternak I'd say that depends a lot on how many points you have. Look at the plethora of questions where the first few comments are a request for an MWE. Just as the site tells commenters to be nice, it should also ask users to always provide an MWE, we waste sooo much time without it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is off-topic with the tags I hope to have understood your request. I have used `xy` package without the hard tip arrows  with the options `[all,cmtip]` leaving your babel `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}`.

PS: I have only thinked an alternative.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. 
\begin{align*}
\xymatrix@1{
A\ar[r]^A & B}  
\end{align*}
The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.
\begin{align*}
\xymatrix@1{
A\ar[r]^A & B}  
\end{align*}
Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops
\end{document}
```

[image]