# \AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd} hasn't any effect

Tags: babel, tikz-cd, shorthands, lthooks

Several `babel` modules (e.g. the `ngerman` one) make active the `"` character, and this is the source of troubles with the `tikz-cd` package and the `tikz`' `babel` library may be not enough (see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536768/18401)).

As a workaround, I can insert `\shorthandoff{"}` and `\shorthandon{"}` respectively before and after the `tikzcd` environments. But, because this becomes tedious, I would want to automate this with `\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd}` and `\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzcd}`. But this hasn't any effect: in the following MCE, the compilation fails at the second `tikzcd` environment.

```
\documentclass[
, ngerman
, english
]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{babel}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{"}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    X\ar[-stealth,r,swap,"p" ] \&
    Y \ar[-stealth,l,swap,bend right=30,"s"]
  \end{tikzcd}
}
\shorthandon{"}%

\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd}{%
  \shorthandoff{"}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzcd}{%
  \shorthandon{"}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    X\ar[-stealth,r,swap,"p" ] \&
    Y \ar[-stealth,l,swap,bend right=30,"s"]
  \end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your tikzcd is in an argument, and so catcode are fixed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. But never mind: my attempt would fail in any case since `\shorthandoff{"}` should be not before `\begin{tikzcd}`, but before (in the example) `\fbox` :$

Comment: Maybe with `BeforeBeginEnvironment`, it woulld work?

Comment: @Bernard In fact, it is `BeforeBeginEnvironment` that I had in mind (in symmetry with `\AfterEndEnvironment`) and wrongly mentioned `\AtBeginEnvironment`. But neither of them works.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not `tikzcd` related because simple `\shorthandoff{"}` does not work inside `\fbox`. You can check this by comparing `\fbox{\shorthandoff{"}-""-}` with `\shorthandoff{"}\fbox{-""-}`.

Comment: @Kpym IMO, `tikz-cd` is partially the culprit as it heavily relies on `"`, which is a pain since this character is active with many `babel`'s languages. And `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}\begin{document}\fbox{"Foo"}\end{document}` compiles like a charm.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé What I'm saying is that you have no chance to solve the problem with `\AtBeginEnvironment` because this will insert `\shorthandoff{"}` inside the `\fbox` and it will not work (like in my previous example). If you wan to use `tikzcd` inside `\fbox` probably you should redefine `\fbox` in a way to add `\shorthandoff{"}` before it.

Comment: @Kpym Ah, OK. That's what I said in the comment above, answering the Ulrike's one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikZ can't do much when it is part of an argument which “fixes” the catcodes (the argment is read already).

You could define your own box macro that – before it grabs the argument – switches of the shorthands and only then grabs it. For example:

```
\newcommand*\BitouzeBox{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}\BitouzeBoxInternal}
\newcommand*\BitouzeBoxInternal[1]{\fbox{#1}\endgroup}
```

which you can use as

```
\BitouzeBox{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    X \ar[-stealth, r, swap, "p" ] \&
    Y \ar[-stealth, l, swap, bend right=30, "s"]
  \end{tikzcd}%
}
```

without having to worry about turning off shorthands. (However, that still means you can't use `babel`s shorthands inside the diagram but you can always use `\babelshorthand{"-}`.)

However, if all you need is a box around your CD then have TikZ draw them.
In the code below I'm defining a style `fbox` that is to be used as an option to a `tikzpicture` or the `tikzcd` environment which draws a `\fbox` around your picture. I'm explicitly using the same length that are used by `\fbox` so that the outcome is the same.

The [`backgrounds` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664104/16595) offers similar keys and more customization.

### Code

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\newcommand*\BitouzeBox{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}\BitouzeBoxInternal}
\newcommand*\BitouzeBoxInternal[1]{\fbox{#1}\endgroup}
\tikzset{fbox/.style={
  /tikz/execute at end picture={\draw[line width=\fboxrule]
              ([shift={(-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                                       current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle ([shift={( \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth, \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                                       current bounding box.north east);}}}
\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{"}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    X\ar[-stealth,r,swap,"p" ] \&
    Y \ar[-stealth,l,swap,bend right=30,"s"]
  \end{tikzcd}% ← !
}

\shorthandon{"}%
\BitouzeBox{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    X \ar[-stealth, r, swap, "p" ] \&
    Y \ar[-stealth, l, swap, bend right=30, "s"]
  \end{tikzcd}% ← !
}

\begin{tikzcd}[fbox] % no ampersand replacement anymore!
  X \ar[-stealth, r, swap, "p" ] &
  Y \ar[-stealth, l, swap, bend right=30, "s"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, we could also use another character instead of `"` for the labels but that's unnecessary work when the `babel` library already exists and helps a good deal.