# Clash between Tikz and Babel (czech) when in newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, babel

I am trying to compile an old document, which uses in many occasions `tikzpicture` passed as an argument to a user defined command. While I understand this might not be an ideal design, it is not in my power to change it.

The problem is that the active char `-` causes clash between `tikz` and czech `babel`. This can be solved via `babel` tikzlibrary. However, as already discussed in [Babel, active chars, ifthenelse and tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314884/babel-active-chars-ifthenelse-and-tikz#314891) the workaround does not work when the `tikzpicutre` is used as an argument of a command. The post above provides a solution for french Babel, however, here, the problem is slightly different and the proposed fix does not apply here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\foo{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, rotate=-90] at (0,0) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

Comment: `\shorthandoff{-}` after begin document should work.

Comment: Will this have any unintended consequences with respect to `babel`?

Comment: depends on if you use the shorthand or not, but you can always reactivate it with `\shorthandon{-}`.

Comment: I am not sure. I don't activate nor deactivate it manually within the document. I rely on babel to do the hyphenation (I assume this is related) even defining my own rules. Is there a way to use `shorthandoff/on{-}` within the tikzpicture or the custom command? My naive attempts on this fail.

Comment: If you don't use the `-` shorthands in your documents then you can just `\shorthandoff{-}` as @UlrikeFischer said. If you do, it gets more complicated. (`\foo` fixes the catcodes of its argument so TikZ (or the `babel` library) can't do their magic anymore.) You coud define `\foo` similar to how I defined [the box macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665758) in a somewhat related answer. (For example: `\newcommand*\foo{\shorthandoff{-}\fooInternal}\newcommand*\fooInternal[1]{#1\shorthandon{-}}`)

Comment: What is `\foo` really doing? Maybe there's a better way to do it.